# What does "this computer has 0 bytes disk space" mean

Tags: 16.04

When I tried to erase disk and install Ubuntu on Windows 10 this window came up to alert me

```
This computer has 0 bytes, free up disk space.
```

The installation then crashed. However after choosing the erase option Windows 10 was lost, and all other attempts failed the same way. I am now sitting at gnu GRUB command line. Can anyone help me solve this issue?

Comment: Did you try to install Ubuntu on the same partition with Windows 10?

Comment: No, I just chose the erase and install option. So I thought it took care of this automaticallu, however before trying to install I did partition 10 gb for the process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I'm hoping that you didn't want Windows. At this point you can put in the Ubuntu live CD and during the install choose the `Erase disk and install Ubuntu` option and just let Ubuntu do everything.

If that fails use the `something else` option and see what the drive looks like.

At this point I can't tell you how you should proceed. I don't know the size of the drive or the system specs. Basically you will need to remove all existing  partitions then create a root partition `/` and a swap partition `/swap` but the sizes will depend on your system.

Once you have the hard drive set up you will be able to click the `Install Now` button and it will install Ubuntu.

If you do want Windows on the system as well .. you will first have to install Windows again... best  would be to remove all partitions during the Windows install .. .let the Windows installer recreate the drive structure... once Windows is installed and working again .. then use the Ubuntu live CD and choose the `Install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS alongside Windows` option.

UPDATED ANSWER for using the `Something else` option for OP's specific issue

If you are dealing with just the two partitions in the `Something else` as described make note of the exact number so you can recreate them.

Select the `/dev/sda1` partition and press the "-" button

Select the `swap` partition and also press the "-" button

This should leave you with the following

```
/dev/sda
 freespace
```

At this point all of the hard drive should be free space.

Now click on freespace and press the "+" button

Change the `size` to the size of the large partition

Leave it set to `Primary` and `Beginning of this space` it should already be using `Ext4`

Change the `Mounting point:` to `/` and click OK

Click on `freespace` again and click the `"+"`

Here leave everything at the top the same and change `Use as:` to `swap area` and click OK

Now you should have something that looks like  this

```
/dev/sda
 /dev/sda1 ext4 / <size of partition>MB
 /dev/sda5 swap   <size of partition>MB
```

Highlight `/dev/sda1` and click the `Install Now` button. That should work if you have the UEFI stuff set as  it should be.

Comment: if that's how the partitions are set up already you should be able to click the `Install Now` and it should work ... if it still give error .. delete those partitions making note of the numbers it was using .. and then recreate those partitions again .. it sound like they are set up with good sizes for your system.

Comment: this may be a UEFI issue too ... is your computer running a UEFI or BIOS .. if you are unsure what this is ... when you enter your `"BIOS"` screen do you have the ability of using a mouse/touchpad or just keyboard. If you can use  a 'pointing device' its a UEFI. I am not real familiar with using one  with Ubuntu but I think there are some settings you have to change.

Comment: well it would be best to start another question on this because this may take some trouble shooting and the comments are getting very long for this already ... they dont like a bunch of responses in the comment section . if you want to  start a chat I will join it and try to help you out

Answer (score 0):

Solved: Go to Settings>Storage>Controller:SATA (check this configurations, it worked for me)